# membersrvc.yaml with password stored in clear-text?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I'm working with hyperledger fabric in the stable version.

In the CA, the users with their password are stored in clear-text on the **membersrvc.yaml** file in $GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/membersrvc.

Is it normal ? Is there an other way to create the users when I launch the CA without having the crendentials in clear text ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The userid/password combination present in the membersrvc.yaml can be used **only once**. Think about it as an OTP. If you want to reuse it again, you have to bring down the membership service instance and you have to clean up the user data store in the  /var/hyperledger/production/db directory (And as of now, as per my information, there are no plans to include a logout API which might have enabled the usage of the credentials again without clean up).

If you want to add a new user to the Fabric, then this can be done programatically with the ***Member.register method - while using Node.js SDK.*** But the user would exist only during the life cycle of the Fabric ( ie, till a clean up is performed).

Comment: I see, thank you for the answer. I will add my new users with Node.js SDK then